# unable to input negative value in power for an int variable in remix

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, blockchain, remix

I want to input the following values to this function

```
function rebase(uint256 epoch, int256 supplyDelta)
```

- epoch (5 minutes later)
- supplyDelta -0.000000000000001

I tried doing so in remix but got an error. How to resolve this issue?

> errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid BigNumber string
> (argument="value", value="-0.000000000000001", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT,
> version=bignumber/5.4.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wierd, it seems to read your input as `1*10^-15`, you sure you really typed `-1*10^15`? anyways if it still doesnt work after double checking i suggest inputting the full number with all the 0s written

Comment: I inputted -0.000000000000001 , made the correction in my code

Comment: Im still facing this issue. Unresolved till now

Comment: using `-1000000000000000` directly doesnt work either?

Comment: That is a different number. I want to use "-0.000000000000001" specifically

Comment: Oh, thats not what your question was at first lol. Well you cant. There's no decimals in solidity

Comment: Okay so what will be the workaround? Cant seem to find a solution since yesterday

Comment: make -0.000000000000001 = -1 and -1 = -1000000000000000 in your code. Same principle as ERC20s decimals

Comment: I didnt add this in code once the contract is deployed already, I manually call the function and give parameters there

Comment: Then it's most likely already accounted for in the code somewhere, probably 1 in that case is 10^-18

Comment: Thanks I made the changes myself and its working now